# Android ListView 'flash' when row clicked is off

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view that displays TextViews which have been spanned so that Links in the text are actionable.

When a user clicks the row, not on a link, I'd like the row to 'flash' so that the user knows they have clicked it ok.

I there a way to re-enable the row selected flash?

Comment: I've wondered this too. I can't figure out how to get it to do it =\